# How to remove axis labels in R matplot?

Tags: r, graph, axis

Help to remove axis labels on graphs.

Hello. I am making some graphs in R and I want to remove the axis on some of them. I am using matplot. On some graphs I want to remove the X axis, on some the Y axis, and on some both. When I look online I can't seem to find how to do it as most information on this is about using ggplot or other packages.

```
output.df <- read.csv("E:\\bla\\data.csv")

matplot(output.df[, 1], output.df[, -1], type="l",
main="Title",xlab=" ", ylab="Percentage",
xlim=c(1970, 2015), ylim=c(0, 100),
lwd=c(1, 4, 4, 4),
col=c("black", "red", "burlywood", "cadetblue"), 
lty=c("solid", "dotted", "dotted", "dotted" ))
```

The X axis has dates on it... I would like to figure out how to remove these dates. I am guessing that the code to remove the Y axis would be the same or almost the same.

Comment: `xaxt="n"` and `yaxt="n"` I think. `matplot` is just a wrapper around standard base R plotting so all the options in `?par` can be used.

Comment: It worked and is great. Thank you so much! 

It removed the tick marks, though I do not need those. Perhaps someone else might want them to remain - can that be done?

Comment: You can add an axis in manually using `axis`, whether it is just tick marks or both labels and tick marks - `axis(1, labels=FALSE)` for instance.